# YUI3 Event Delegation for Applying Style to List Element

Tags: events, yui3

I know event delegation in this form:

```
anItem = Y.one('ul#id');
anItem.delegate('click', aFunction, 'selector');
```

What event to use for applying style to each li created dynamically? 
I will run addClass() to each li/new li.

I tried like this:

```
anItem.delegate('onchange', aFunction, 'selector');
```

I have tried with 'change' event as well. But no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What elements are selected by `'selector'`? The `onchange` event is only valid for `INPUT`, `SELECT` and `TEXTAREA` elements. See the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents).

Comment: I forgot the exact situation. I was trying to add delegate on UL So the selector was for UL. But it looks that was also coming dynamically. So, I have tied the event with 'contentready'.

Then I tried to tie the event with Input box due to which li is changing. But I saw the 'changevalue' is not available before YUI V 3.4. Then there was 'key' synthetic event as well. I forgot what I have done with the problem.

Comment: Ok, well, you can't listen for an onchange event on an LI element. I don't think they bubble either, but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: Ok, I have selected your comment as an answer to close it. Thanks for reply.